# Django admin how to show a progress bar in percentage

Tags: python, html, django-admin

In the Django built-in admin site, how can I show a progress bar in the Change List pages and Change Form page as a field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example:

1. Create method `percentage_paid` in your model to calculate the result and render an HTML element.

```py
# models.py

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ....
    def percentage_paid(self):
        if self.paid_amount and self.final_price:
            percentage = round((self.paid_amount / self.final_price * 100), 2)
        else:
            percentage = 0
        return format_html(
            '''
            <progress value="{0}" max="100"></progress>
            <span style="font-weight:bold">{0}%</span>
            ''',
            percentage
        )
```

2. Add this method field `'percentage_paid'` to `readonly_filds`
3. Meanwhile, add it to `list_display` if you want to show in Change List Page and or `fields` if want it in Change Form Page. I add it to `fieldsets` to customize my Change Form.

```py
# admin.py

class CaseAdmin(CommonInfoAdmin):
    fieldsets = CommonInfoAdmin.fieldsets + (
        ('Sales Summary', {
            'fields': (
                ....
                ('final_price', 'paid_amount', 'balance', 'percentage_paid'),
                ....
            )
        }),
    )
    readonly_fields = [
        ....
        'percentage_paid',
    ]
    list_display = (
        ....
        'percentage_paid'
    )
```

The results:

- Change List

[image: Change List]

- Change Form

[image: Change Form]